# redefined section configuration \Configure{likesection} in TeX4HT shows error

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht, tex4ebook

I redefined the configuration of \section and \section* in `cfg` file for modifying the HTML output, I am getting the below error (see the screenshot below). I used `amsart.cls`, when changing class file to `article.cls` it is compiling without error.

what is the issue when using other `cls` file apart from `article.cls` and help me to rectify the below error.

I run the file through `make4ht.exe -l -a debug -u -c mycfg.cfg <filename>.tex` and `Texlive 2022`

[image]

My CFG:

```
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\Preamble{xhtml,uni-html4,mathjax,charset=UTF-8,fn-in,NoFonts,ext=.xhtml}

\makeatletter

\Configure{section}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading1">}\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>0 \thesection.\space\fi}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
                   
\Configure{subsection}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading2">\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>1\thesubsection.\space\fi}}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}

\Configure{subsubsection}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading3">\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>2\thesubsubsection.\space\fi}}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}

\Configure{paragraph}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading4">\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>3\theparagraph.\space\fi}}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}

\Configure{subparagraph}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading5">\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>4\thesubparagraph.\space\fi}}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
                   
\makeatother                   

\Configure{likesection}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                        \HCode{\Hnewline}}
                       {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                       {\HCode{<p class="heading1">}}
                       {\HCode{</p>}}   
                
\Configure{likesubsection}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                        \HCode{\Hnewline}}
                       {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                       {\HCode{<p class="heading2">}}
                       {\HCode{</p>}} 

\Configure{likesubsubsection}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                        \HCode{\Hnewline}}
                       {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                       {\HCode{<p class="heading3">}}
                       {\HCode{</p>}} 

\Configure{likeparagraph}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                        \HCode{\Hnewline}}
                       {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                       {\HCode{<p class="heading4">}}
                       {\HCode{</p>}} 

\Configure{likesubparagraph}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                        \HCode{\Hnewline}}
                       {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                       {\HCode{<p class="heading5">}}
                       {\HCode{</p>}}    

\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[numbers]{amsart}


\begin{document}

\section{Head Level 1}

In the random walk setting, however, invariant measures may fail to exist, and measures that are invariant on average-- i.e., stationary-- take their place. Kukutani showed that tationary measures always exist. Stationary measures can be thought of as a weaker analogue of invariant measures, and they serve many of the same purposes. Thus, it is useful to study when a given stationary measure is genuinely invariant, and when invariant measures exist in a random dynamical system at all. 

\section*{Head Level 1}

In the random walk setting, however, invariant measures may fail to exist, and measures that are invariant on average-- i.e., stationary-- take their place. Kukutani showed that tationary measures always exist. Stationary measures can be thought of as a weaker analogue of invariant measures, and they serve many of the same purposes. Thus, it is useful to study when a given stationary measure is genuinely invariant, and when invariant measures exist in a random dynamical system at all. 

\subsection{Head Level 2}

In the random walk setting, however, invariant measures may fail to exist, and measures that are invariant on average-- i.e., stationary-- take their place. Kukutani showed that tationary measures always exist. Stationary measures can be thought of as a weaker analogue of invariant measures, and they serve many of the same purposes. Thus, it is useful to study when a given stationary measure is genuinely invariant, and when invariant measures exist in a random dynamical system at all.

\subsection*{Head Level 2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there really isn't any support for configurations of starred sectioning commands with the `amsart` class. I've tried to copy their definitions from the configuration file for `article`, which fixed the error, but `\Configure{likesection}` didn't have any effect on the output code, the code from `\Configure{section}` was used.

I've digged into the source codes and found  that the `amsart` class uses a different underlying code for sectioning commands than the standard LaTeX classes. In particular, the original `\section` command calls either `\@sect` or `\@ssect` commands, depending on the use of the star. In `amsart`, it calls `\@sect` in both cases, so the code that TeX4ht provides for `likesection` is never used.

As your configurations for unstarred sectioning commands work for both unstarred and starred version, the simples fix is to simply remove all variants of `\Configure{like...}` from your config file:

```
\RequirePackage{multirow}
\Preamble{xhtml,uni-html4,mathjax,charset=UTF-8,fn-in,NoFonts,ext=.xhtml}

\makeatletter

\Configure{section}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading1">}\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>0 \thesection.\space\fi}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
                   
\Configure{subsection}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading2">\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>1\thesubsection.\space\fi}}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}

\Configure{subsubsection}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading3">\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>2\thesubsubsection.\space\fi}}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}

\Configure{paragraph}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading4">\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>3\theparagraph.\space\fi}}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}

\Configure{subparagraph}{\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP\IgnorePar%
                    \HCode{\Hnewline}%
                    \HCode{<p class="heading5">\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>4\thesubparagraph.\space\fi}}
                   {\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{}}
                   {\HCode{</p>}\HtmlParOn\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
                   
\makeatother                   


\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

```html
<p class='heading1' id='head-level-'>1. <a id='x1-10001'></a>Head Level 1</p>
<!-- l. 9 --><p class='noindent'>In the random walk setting, however, invariant measures may fail to exist, and measures
that are invariant on average– i.e., stationary– take their place. Kukutani showed that
tationary measures always exist. Stationary measures can be thought of as
a weaker analogue of invariant measures, and they serve many of the same
purposes. Thus, it is useful to study when a given stationary measure is genuinely
invariant, and when invariant measures exist in a random dynamical system at
all.
</p>
   
<p class='heading1' id='head-level-1'>1. <a id='x1-2000'></a>Head Level 1</p>
<!-- l. 13 --><p class='noindent'>In the random walk setting, however, invariant measures may fail to exist, and measures
that are invariant on average– i.e., stationary– take their place. Kukutani showed that
tationary measures always exist. Stationary measures can be thought of as
a weaker analogue of invariant measures, and they serve many of the same
purposes. Thus, it is useful to study when a given stationary measure is genuinely
invariant, and when invariant measures exist in a random dynamical system at
all.
</p>
   
<p class='heading2' id='head-level-2'><a id='x1-30001.1'></a>Head Level 2</p>
<!-- l. 17 --><p class='noindent'>In the random walk setting, however, invariant measures may fail to exist, and measures
that are invariant on average– i.e., stationary– take their place. Kukutani showed that
tationary measures always exist. Stationary measures can be thought of as
a weaker analogue of invariant measures, and they serve many of the same
purposes. Thus, it is useful to study when a given stationary measure is genuinely
invariant, and when invariant measures exist in a random dynamical system at
all.
</p>
   
<p class='heading2' id='head-level-3'><a id='x1-4000'></a>Head Level 2</p>
```